# Get EditText's value from sub Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext

How to get EditText's value from sub-Activity? With a condition that if I click back button on the phone, there's no error in Sub-Activity?

This is my **Sub-Activity** code:

```
    public class SBooksSearch extends Activity {
    private EditText mTextSearch;   
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.sbooks_search); 

        mTextSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_search);     
        Button searchButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_search);        

        searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){                
                Intent data = new Intent();             
                data.putExtra(SBooksDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE_RAW, mTextSearch.getText().toString());         
                setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }   

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);        
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();

    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();       
    }
}
```

This is my **Activity-Result:**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);        
switch(requestCode){
case ACTIVITY_SEARCH:
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
mTitleRaw = extras != null ? extras.getString(SBooksDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE_RAW) : null;            
     if(mTitleRaw!=null){
      Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.searchData(mTitleRaw);

    String[] from = new String[]{ SBooksDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID,
                        SBooksDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE, SBooksDbAdapter.KEY_LYRICS };
        int[] to = new int[]{ R.id.id, R.id.title, R.id.lyrics };
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = 
                    new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.sbooks_row, cursor, from, to );
           setListAdapter(adapter);
            }           
           break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You mean you want to return a string to the calling activity? startActivityForResult(...) & setResult(resultCode, data) then.

Comment: I want to get the String value from TextView in Sub-Activity. But  when I open the Sub-Activity and then I click back button on the Phone It throw an exception error. The problem is when I try to solve the exception error (manage activity life cycle), there's no exception anymore, but I cannot get the String value!!!

So how can I get the String and hit the back button on the phone without an exception?

Comment: Can you post some code snippets so it's easier to understand exactly what you're attempting and why a startActivityForResult call won't do what you need?

Comment: Oh, really Sorry, I have a confusing here. I mean EditText not TextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't be attempting any sort of action if the user hits the "back" button. It's a global button that means "get me out of here now", and it's usually understood that the user wants nothing other than going back one screen to occur as a result of that.

So what you need to do is in your searchButton.setOnClickListener, in the onClick, create an empty Intent like so:

```
Intent data = new Intent();
```

Then you need to be adding the value of your EditText as an extra value, like so:

```
data.putExtra(SBooksDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE_RAW, mTextSearch.getText().toString());
```

Finally, include this intent in your setResult call:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
```

In your onActivityResult pull the value out of the intent like you're already doing and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks MattC , but I try with your code but I don't know why there's no thing on my ListView after Click "Search" button? I think there's no data pull back, do you have any idea about this?

Comment: If you debug the code and set a breakpoint, is the value returned by extras.getString(SBooksDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE_RAW) the value that was in the EditText box?

Comment: After debugging, the value return is "null". I don't know why?

Comment: There's one point, When I change the code Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); With Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
The result is OK, but when Click Back "button" on the phone it throw an error. On the contrary, the value is null.

Comment: When you debug, what does mTextSearch.getText() return? I do this in a lot of places in a few of my apps and it works like a charm so I'm not really sure what's going on with yours :(

Comment: Hi MattC, Your code is ok, and I can get the value back to my Main-Acivity. But what happen when you are in the Sub-Activity and you don't put the value and you click Back "button" on the phone? You see it will throw an exception.
 So, to make sure no error exception appear, I must check the the value in the Intent before I do something with it. Finally, I can sovle the problem! (Maybe you want to see it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265095/control-the-back-button-in-android )
Thanks for your answer.