# Keep webView page already loaded?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, webview

I have created a browser that has a button to open a new tab. When I click back it goes back to the previous activity with webview. The problem is that I don't want it to reload the page again when I backpress. Also the same thing happens when the screen rotates. Is there any specific function to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post your code so that users can see suggest you something.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Control the back "button" in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265095/control-the-back-button-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Override your WebView's [onPageStarted](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageStarted(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.Bitmap)) method to be like that

```
@Override
   public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
   {
    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    String htmlContent = getRemoteContent(url);
    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(url, htmlContent, null, "utf-8", url);
   }
```

Comment: It says " the method getRemoteContent(String) is undefined for the type MyWebView (which is the name of the class)". What should i do?